# At what point in the movie did Ruby Sparks become real and how?

Tags: plot-explanation, ruby-sparks

In the movie **Ruby Sparks** (2012), Calvin creates a love interest for himself with a type writer. He gives her a history and a personality. No one but him can see her.

[image: Calvin discovered she is real h]

What I want to know is:

**At what point and how did Ruby become real and visible to everyone else without Calvin making her visible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No one but him can see her.

### You are mistaken.

**At no point is Ruby invisible to anyone.**

Immediately after Ruby appears Calvin meets up with a girl at the cafe and although he *ignores* Ruby and the girl isn't aware that she's being addressed as she's really into Calvin it's clear that she's visible and real from the very start.

She doesn't take **physical form** until we see her in the kitchen. Up to that point she's in his head as an imaginary person.

*So she's not invisible at all...there was nothing there to see.*

She went from completely imaginary to completely real which is the *entire premise* of the movie.

*There is no explanation given which is part of the charm of the movie*.

Comment: Then how does Calvin's brother see her? It is clear that he can see her. You say in your answer; *No one can see her* and *So she's not invisible at all...there was nothing to see* are a bit overstated (no offense), if there was nothing to see... why, when Calvin ran off with Ruby over his shoulder after the meeting at the cafe, did people offer Ruby to call the police for her? She is clearly visible then, and Calvin saying: *Holy s**t, you're real, you're real! If you believe that she was pure imagination, why did these events happen in the movie?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are asking. Until she appears in the kitchen she's imaginary,. From then on, she's real. Why? Because it's a miracle.